# Corner radius for MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am new to iOS development. I want to play a video. So I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play my video. Now I want to set the corner radius for this video. Don't know how to do it?

I tried `layer.cornerRadius` for the backgroundview from the storyboard. It is not working.

Here is my movie player code

```
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
 if let player = moviePlayer {
player.view.frame = videoBackgroundView.bounds
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .Fill
            videoBackgroundView.addSubview(player.view)

        }
```

**Is it possible to set corner for video?** Please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Try with a `mask` applied to the layer, but in this way you will lose the video in the corner

Comment: How to do that? Any sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can apply the `cornerRadius` to `player.view.layer` (maybe? I have to try it).
Anyway you can apply a mask to that layer

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: player.view.frame,
            byRoundingCorners: .AllCorners,
            cornerRadii: YOUR_RADIUS
        )

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = player.view.frame;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

player.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```